# Compilation problem with make

Tags: compiling, make

While trying to build, I get a lot of warnings. I do the following in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb):

```
!git clone -qqq https://github.com/nu774/mp4fpsmod.git > /dev/null
!sudo apt-get update -y -qqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -y -qqq autoconf libtool > /dev/null
%cd mp4fpsmod
!./bootstrap.sh
!./configure
```

All the above commands were done successfully but when I run `make` a lot of warnings appear:

```
!make

make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/content/mp4fpsmod'
Making all in mp4v2
make[2]: Entering directory '/content/mp4fpsmod/mp4v2'
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I./include -I./include -I. -I.  -Wall -Wformat -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -c -o src/3gp.lo src/3gp.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I./include -I./include -I. -I. -Wall -Wformat -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -c src/3gp.cpp -o src/3gp.o
In file included from ./src/src.h:28:0,
                 from ./src/impl.h:6,
                 from src/3gp.cpp:28:
./src/mp4util.h:36:33: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and string macro [-Wliteral-suffix]
             throw new Exception("assert failure: "LIBMPV42_STRINGIFY((expr)), __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__ ); \
                                 ^
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I./include -I./include -I. -I.  -Wall -Wformat -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -c -o src/atom_ac3.lo src/atom_ac3.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I./include -I./include -I. -I. -Wall -Wformat -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -c src/atom_ac3.cpp -o src/atom_ac3.o
In file included from ./src/src.h:28:0,
                 from ./src/impl.h:6,
                 from src/atom_ac3.cpp:24:
./src/mp4util.h:36:33: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and string macro [-Wliteral-suffix]
             throw new Exception("assert failure: "LIBMPV42_STRINGIFY((expr)), __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__ ); \
```

How can I fix this? If I ignore all the warnings will it affect `mp4fpsmod`?

Comment: You might be able to edit `src/3gp.cpp` line 28 and `src/atom_ac3.cpp` line 24 so the exception isn't thrown.

Comment: The list of errors is not limited by `3gp.cpp` and `atom_ac3.cpp`. Copypaste my code to Colab and you will see a lot more files with errors.

Comment: Those appear to be warnings - do you get any actual errors? If so please [edit] your question to include them.